# On the no trivial $3$-tuples $(p, q, \alpha) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^p =\Big [\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^q\Big]^\alpha $.

Tags: number-theory

It is well known that $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^3 =\Big [\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^1\Big]^2$.  My question is very simple.

> There are   $3$-tuples $(p, q, \alpha) \in
>  \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, in addition to $(3,1,2)$,
>    such that $\alpha\geq 2$ and  $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{\,p} =\Big [\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\,q}\Big]^\alpha, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}{\;\Large ?}$$

Comment: @CalvinLin As I said non-trivial cases. And this means that $\alpha\geq 0$.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? If so then other than $(p, q, \alpha)=(p, p, 1)$ and $(3, 1, 2)$, there are no more such $3$-tuples.

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The following claims should be obvious, and will not be proven.]

Claim: The degree of $ \sum_{i=1}^n i^r$ is $r+1$.

Claim: The leading coefficient of $ \sum_{i=1}^n i^r$ is $\frac{1}{r+1} $.

The first claim gives us $p+1 = \alpha (q+1) $. The second claim gives us $\frac{1}{p+1} = \left( \frac{ 1}{q+1} \right)^\alpha$.

Multiplying these two equations, we get $(q+1) = \alpha^\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$

Claim: $1 \leq \alpha^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}} \leq 2$, with equality if and only if $\alpha = 1, 2$.

With this claim, the RHS is never an integer except for $\alpha = 1, 2 $.

If $\alpha = 1$, then $p+1 = q+1, p=q$.
If $\alpha = 2$, this forces $q+1=2$ or $q=1$, and that $p+1 = 2(q+1) $ so $p=3$.

Finally, verify that $(p,p,1) $ and $(3,1,2)$ are solutions.

Comment: $+1$ Nice. I sort of overkilled it with Mihailescu...

Comment: @IvanLoh Lol, yes. This is the approach I used in the past when thinking about it. I haven't seen the proof of Mihai, and I avoid using it as the only proof approach. The 'insane' version of this problem, is to throw $n$ in as a parameter too (e.g. you did the $n=2$ case).

Comment: @CalvinLin  simplicity with which you solved the issue made ​​me embarrassed. Very nice your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2$, so $(1+2^p)=(1+2^q)^{\alpha}$, so $(1+2^q)^{\alpha}-2^p=1$. If $p=1$, then $q=\alpha=1$, contradicting $\alpha \geq 2$. Otherwise $1+2^q, \alpha, 2, p>1$, so by [Mihailescu's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) $1+2^q=3, \alpha=2, p=3$. This gives $(3, 1, 2)$, which is indeed a solution.